# Turning 1-D array into a multi-channel matrix using delay process

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, matrix, audio

The single channel received data is a one dimensional matrix. That's basically my audio input. I need to expand the dimension of this matrix to apply some multi-channel algorithms on it. The paper (Improvement of Source Number Estimation Method for Single Channel Signal) I read tells me they achieved this by using the delay process, where the single channel data is denoted as:

y(n), n=1,2,...,L and the received signal as yi = y(n+(i-1)d)

With this, a N-channel received data is formed as following:
Y =

```
[y(n)
 y(n+d)
 ..
 y(n+(N-1)d)]
```

where d is the delay length of each channel. (I'm sorry about the bad matrix, I'm new to this)
However, I'm having trouble converting this into python codes. I'm new to coding, and I've been trying for days but I just can't figure out how to do this part. Can someone please help me? Would it be easier if I used Matlab for this?

Comment: Do you have any sample which you have and the desired output which you want? If you provide a minimal simple example, maybe we can help you with that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think in MATLAB this would be `Y = y(bsxfun(@plus, 1:L, d*(0:N-1)'))`